# GeoServer cascading WMS, FeatureInfo is lost

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm trying to cascade a WMS service in GeoServer (http://grb.agiv.be/geodiensten/raadpleegdiensten/GRB/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS).

I can view the cascaded layers just fine, but whenever I try to get FeatureInfo from a cascaded layer I get an error message saying that the layer isn't queryable.

I can get the FeatureInfo from the original service, so I know that there is actual FeatureInfo on the original layers.

I've combed through every available WMS setting in GeoServer but only found the 'Queryable' option in the 'WMS Settings' panel in the Publishing tab of the cascaded layers, which is obviously enabled.

Is there anything I'm missing, or is it just not possible to get FeatureInfo from a cascaded WMS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging around I contacted the GeoServer-users mailinglist, and got an answer:

The problem is tied to the response of the server I'm trying to cascade.

The GML response from the WMS server is not a standard feature collection but some weird msGMLOutput construct that would need a custom parser.

To interpret it, real GML seems to start only at the third nested element.
So, this would need someone writing such parser.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GSIP+47+-+WMS+cascading):

> GetFeatureInfo cascading for servers that do support the application/vnd.ogc.gml feature info format. Works in both standard and reprojected case.

It seems that your [server](http://grb.agiv.be/geodiensten/raadpleegdiensten/GRB/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS) does provide that format but I haven't actually tested that it does. You may need to make sure that your request is also in that format?

So the bottom line is that it should be working - can you check what the request that is sent to the remote server looks like (may be with wireshark if you don't have access to the remote logs).

Comment: GeoServer actually sends the FeatureInfo request to the WMS server and also gets a GML response which contains correct information, I put the request and response in a Pastebin file: http://pastebin.com/PEiU9kaE

I don't understand why GeoServer gets an actual vnd.ogc.gml response with information, but still says the layer isn't queryable...

Comment: what format did you ask for in your request?

Comment: The format asked is also application/vnd.ogc.gml

Comment: I actually just realized that I don't get the 'not queryable' error, I just get an empty response from GeoServer in Gaia: 'no features were found'.

With the internal OpenLayers preview I get the 'loading, please wait' message for a few seconds, also with no results.
When I check the nodelist div which should contain the feature info I just see a title and some inline table css, but also no actual information

Answer (score 0):

As per @iant's comment.

The [following URL](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html#features) on the geoserver docs says it all:

> WMS GetFeatureInfo requests will be passed to the
>   remote WMS. If the remote WMS supports the **application/vnd.ogc.gml**
>   format the request will be successful.

You can check available formats in the XML output on your GetCapabilities URL:

[image]